# Using iloc on a dataframe gives me out of bound errors even when using a list of indices derived from the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a DataFrame with about 400,000 columns. When I try to get all the data using iloc, it throws out of bound errors. Here is what I have tried.

> index_second_update = the_data.index.tolist()
>
> the_data.iloc[index_second_update]
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py",
> ```
>
> line 2130, in _get_list_axis
>           return self.obj.take(key, axis=axis)
>         File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
>   line 3604, in take
>           indices, axis=self._get_block_manager_axis(axis), verify=True
>         File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py",
>   line 1389, in take
>           indexer = maybe_convert_indices(indexer, n)
>         File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers.py",
>   line 201, in maybe_convert_indices
>           raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")
>       IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py",
> ```
>
> line 1424, in **getitem**
>           return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
>         File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py",
>   line 2148, in _getitem_axis
>           return self._get_list_axis(key, axis=axis)
>         File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py",
>   line 2133, in _get_list_axis
>           raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
>       IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Some more details:

> len(index_second_update) = 446882
>
> index_second_update == the_data.index.tolist()
>
> True

Strange thing is that it breaks down at around 200000 rows. Up until then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.loc` access the pandas by the **label** of each row, which is not necessarily the row number.

here's code that will work for you, that accesses the data by the row label

```py
index_second_update = the_data.index.tolist()

the_data.loc[index_second_update]
```

or even more simply:

```py
the_data.loc[the_data.index]
```

as an example for an index which is not row numbers look in the dataframe below, the rows are labeled by name.

```py
import pandas as pd
csv = """\
Name,Birth Year
Joe,2000
Bill,1998
Mike,1996
Frank,1995"""
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
df.set_index('Name')
```

```
        Birth Year
Name    
Joe     2000
Bill    1998
Mike    1996
Frank   1995
```

Comment: After thinking about it, I'm not sure I get why it was going wrong. I had not selected any indices, nor had I used any group-bys, so shouldn't the row numbers have been my indices?

Comment: well you didnt supply your DataFrame. how about you print the output of `df.info()` and `print(df.index)`